# Can I say "if a sequence is not bounded above, then it is divergent to positive infinity" without explicitly saying it's eventually increasing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definition

I recently learned the following theorem about bounded sequences:

> If a sequence is eventually increasing and not bounded above, then it is divergent to positive infinity.
>
> If a sequence is eventually decreasing and not bounded below, then it is divergent to negative infinity.

Do I have to say "eventually increasing" / "eventually decreasing" when stating this theorem? What if I just say:

> If a sequence is not bounded above, then it is divergent to positive infinity.
>
> If a sequence is not bounded below, then it is divergent to negative infinity.

Am I correct in assuming that the sequence being eventually increasing/decreasing is implied by the sequence not being bounded? Are there any drawbacks to the more concise statement that I may not be aware of?

Comment: You can prove something weaker, you can show that if a sequence is not bounded above then **a subsequence** is divergent to positive infinity.

Comment: A sequence like $a_n = n + (-1)^n(n/2)$ diverges to $+\infty$ but is not "eventually increasing".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to say "eventually increasing" or "eventually decreasing".

Consider the sequence $a_n = (-1)^n n$

It is definitely not bounded (above or below) but it doesn't diverge to $\infty$ nor does it diverge to $-\infty$.

Comment: My other favorite example is $n\sin(n)$.